# How to install iOS 5 beta on device

Tags: iphone, device, ios5

As a registered developer, how can we put iOS 5 beta on our devices?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is under NDA, so we can't discuss it here. But you can log into your developer center and find info about it there, and probably very detailed info in the forums.